# How can I automatically add widgets to the body of my scaffold?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to have the body of my scaffold return list Tiles that are built automatically, much like posts on a social media app. However, it only returns and empty container, with only its background colour.

```
Widget _buildListingWidgets(List<Widget> listing) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => listing[index],
    itemCount: listing.length,
  );
}
```

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final listing = <Listing>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < _listingNames.length; i++) {
    listing.add(Listing(
      describe: _describe[i],
      building: _building[i],
      location: _location[i],
      availability: _availability[i],
    ));
  }
  final listView = Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
    child: _buildListingWidgets(listing),
  );

  ...
```

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: appBar,
  body: listView,

  ...
);
```

Comment: Please re-check the code you have posted and edit it. I think the order of our your code is jumbled (the return statement is gone above the build function)

Comment: @SarveshDalvi There. Does it now make sense?

Comment: Yes, wait I'll look I'll look into it.

Comment: Are you getting an error ?

Comment: No, there is no error but the body is just plain, with only its background colour.

Comment: Send the code of your Listing Widget

Comment: Where do you get _listingNames from? Do you call setState after they are updated?

Answer (score 1):

Keep you code as it now, and modify the ListViewBuilder to look like this:

```
Widget _buildListingWidgets(List<Widget> listing) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: listing.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(child:
     Text(listing[index].describe),
     );
    }        
  );
}
```

It should work.

Comment: There's an error that the getter describe can't be used for type widget.

Comment: Please post your `'Listing` class or widget, how does it look like.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have overly complicated how to build your ListView, without using it's inherent functionality. You can do it this way:

```
class Issue66841743 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: MyList(listingNames: listing,),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List listingNames;

  const MyList({Key key, this.listingNames}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listingNames.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Listing(
            describe: _describe[i],
            building: _building[i],
            location: _location[i],
            availability: _availability[i],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Have in mind that you did not provide us with the other Lists, _describe, _building, _location and _availability. These also signal me that there are further issues in your code. As you very well could have a class with all the properties pertaining to a certain listing.